# Integral $\int\limits_{4}^9\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, roots

Integral for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ gives $2\sqrt{x} + c$. However, when applying the limits, $\sqrt{x}$ gives two answers ($-2$ and $2$ for $4$; $-3$ and $3$ for $9$). Which values should we use? Most solutions give an answer of $2$. Shouldn't there be four answers?

Comment: You always have $\sqrt{x}\ge0$. Thus $\sqrt{4}=2$, $\sqrt{9}=3.$

Comment: Always remember that $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$. The square root always yields a positive number in case you have a confusion. Thus, $\sqrt{4}=2$ and $\sqrt{9}=3$.

Comment: If worried about the sign, draw a diagram. The integral has only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember (for the sake of your sanity) that it is the case that when dealing with the square root **function**, that we have, by definition,

$$\sqrt x\ge0$$

Thus,

$$\int_4^9\frac1{\sqrt x}\ dx=2(\sqrt9-\sqrt4)=2(3-2)=2$$

Comment: I did not really understand this. -2 * -2 also gives 4. So why can't sqrt(4) be -2

Comment: @KarishnuPoddar Because $x=\sqrt4$ is not the same thing as $x^2=4$.  This is why when we use the quadratic formula, for example, that we have $x^2=4\implies x=\pm\sqrt4$.  The square root function on its own does not return negative values.

Comment: @KarishnuPoddar No problem, glad to help.  :D